# In Access, how to merge quickly two linked tables (originally views from SQL Server) in a local Access table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an .accdb Access file and 2 SQL Server databases with 12 views each. Names and structures of the views are the same from one SQLServer database to the other one.
First 12 views are already linked in the Acces file in tables, and those tables are used with request in the VBA code later.

I would like to add the content of 12 views coming from the second database to the content of the 12 first views and continue using the requests as it was before.

### SqlServer :

db1: table1, table2, table3, table4, ... table12;

db2: table1, table2, table3, table4, ... table12 (same names and structures as tables from db1)

### Access file:

links already done to table1 of db1, link to table2 of db1, .... link to table12 of db1
links to do to table1 of db2, link to table2 of db2, .... link to table12 of db2
The goal is to be able to use the merge content of the 12 views from db1, and the 12 view form db2 in the requests after like it is currently

Comment: If you want live updates, then link to db, don't import data. I have never converted to accde but I expect deleting and re-creating tables will not work. Make tables permanent and INSERT/UPDATE. Why do you need to import data to local tables? Question is really too broad.

Comment: I want to import to local tables because there are too much requests to manage after with those tables. Currently we have those 12 linked tabled that are used later in the VBA code with requests. And I just want to use those same requests but add the content of 12 new linked tables. It's too broad, sorry, this comment is explaining better the goal. I'll edit

Comment: It is probably better to do this on Sql Server. Create views there that combine the data. `SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.tableX UNION ALL SELECT * FROM db2.dbo.tableX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, then simply link all 12 tables.

Then assuming you have a local table of the same structure? then you can run a append query like this:

```
Dim strFromTable  As String
Dim strToTable    As String
Dim i             As Integer
Dim strSQL        As String

strFromTable = "dbo_tblData"   ' our 1 - 12 tables
strToTable = "tblLocalTable"

For i = 1 To 12
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strToTable & _
           " SELECT * FROM " & strFromTable & i
   Debug.Print "appending table " & strFromTable
   CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
Next i
```

Now above assumes that the 12 linked tables are named dbo_tblData1, then dbo_tblData2 etc.

If you don't have such a naming convention, then you could change above code to use a different table name that you supply.

You also could consider writing code to create the "linked" table on the fly, but its probably just as easy to link the 12 tables one time, and then above will work.

the above of course pulls all 12 tables into ONE table in Access. You could certainly modify the above to pull each table "from" into a local table.

eg this:

```
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO " & strToTable & i & _
           " SELECT * FROM " & strFromTable & i
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It will help me a lot. My question was closed because it needs details. But it seems you understood it well anyway ;)